# Swift DispatchQueue global and main in variable

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have 3 functions like this:

```
func getMyFirstItem(complete: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        complete(10)
    }
}

func getMySecondtItem(complete: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos:.background).async {
        complete(10)
    }
}

func getMyThirdItem(complete: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        complete(10)
    }
}
```

And I have a variable:

```
var myItemsTotal: Int = 0
```

I would like to know how to sum the items, in this case 10 10 10 to get 30. But what is the best way, since is background and main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key issue is to ensure thread-safety. For example, the following is *not* thread-safe:

```swift
func addUpValuesNotThreadSafe() {
    var total = 0

    getMyFirstItem { value in
        total += value             // on main thread
    }

    getMySecondItem { value in
        total += value             // on some GCD worker thread!!!
    }

    getMyThirdItem { value in
        total += value             // on main thread
    }

    ...
}
```

One could solve this problem by not allowing these tasks run in parallel, but you lose all the benefits of asynchronous processes and the concurrency they offer.

Needless to say, when you do allow them to run in parallel, you would likely add some mechanism (such as dispatch groups) to know when all of these asynchronous tasks are done. But I did not want to complicate this example, but rather keep our focus on the thread-safety issue. (I show how to use dispatch groups later in this answer.)

Anyway, if you have closures called from multiple threads, you must not increment the same `total` without adding some synchronization. You could add synchronization with a serial dispatch queue, for example:

```swift
func addUpValues() {
    var total = 0
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".synchronized")

    getMyFirstItem { value in
        queue.async {
            total += value         // on serial queue
        }
    }

    getMySecondItem { value in
        queue.async {
            total += value         // on serial queue
        }
    }

    getMyThirdItem { value in
        queue.async {
            total += value         // on serial queue
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

There are a variety of alternative synchronization mechanisms (locks, GCD reader-writer, `actor`, etc.). But I start with the serial queue example to observe that, actually, any serial queue would accomplish the same thing. Many use the main queue (which is a serial queue) for this sort of trivial synchronization where the performance impact is negligible, such as in this example.

For example, one could therefore either refactor `getMySecondItem` to also call its completion handler on the main queue, like `getMyFirstItem` and `getMyThirdItem` already do. Or if you cannot do that, you could simply have the `getMySecondItem` caller dispatch the code that needs to be synchronized to the main queue:

```swift
func addUpValues() {
    var total = 0

    getMyFirstItem { value in
        total += value             // on main thread
    }

    getMySecondItem { value in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            total += value         // now on main thread, too
        }
    }

    getMyThirdItem { value in
        total += value             // on main thread
    }

    // ...
}
```

That is also thread-safe. This is why many libraries will ensure that all of their completion handlers are called on the main thread, as it minimizes the amount of time the app developer needs to manually synchronize values.

---

While I have illustrated the use of serial dispatch queues for synchronization, there are a multitude of alternatives. E.g., one might use locks or GCD reader-writer pattern.

The key is that one should never mutate a variable from multiple threads without some synchronization.

---

Above I mention that you need to know when the three asynchronous tasks are done. You can use a `DispatchGroup`, e.g.:

```swift
func addUpValues(complete: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
    let total = Synchronized(0)
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    getMyFirstItem { first in
        total.synchronized { value in
            value += first
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    getMySecondItem { second in
        total.synchronized { value in
            value += second
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    getMyThirdItem { third in
        total.synchronized { value in
            value += third
        }
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        let value = total.synchronized { $0 }
        complete(value)
    }
}
```

And in this example, I abstracted the synchronization details out of `addUpValues`:

```swift
class Synchronized<T> {
    private var value: T
    private let lock = NSLock()

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func synchronized<U>(block: (inout T) throws -> U) rethrows -> U {
        lock.lock()
        defer { lock.unlock() }
        return try block(&value)
    }
}
```

Obviously, use whatever synchronization mechanism you want (e.g., GCD or `os_unfair_lock` or whatever).

But the idea is that in the GCD world, dispatch groups can notify you when a series of asynchronous tasks are done.

---

I know that this was a GCD question, but for the sake of completeness, the Swift concurrency `async`-`await` pattern renders much of this moot.

```swift
func getMyFirstItem() async -> Int {
    return 10
}

func getMySecondItem() async -> Int {
    await Task.detached(priority: .background) {
        return 10
    }.value
}

func getMyThirdItem() async -> Int {
    return 10
}

func addUpValues() {
    Task {
        async let value1 = getMyFirstItem()
        async let value2 = getMySecondItem()
        async let value3 = getMyThirdItem()
        let total = await value1 + value2 + value3
        print(total)
    }
}
```

Or, if your async methods were updating some shared property, you would use an `actor` to synchronize access. See [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/).

Comment: "This is why many libraries will ensure that all of their completion handlers are called on the main thread". Is this always desirable?! I ask for two reasons: 1. the library consumer may not want the completion to be executed on main thread 2. you might know that it's already being dispatched to main and you dispatch it again and so it gets deferred...

Comment: Your point is well taken, but, yes, I think that libraries that offer to call all completion handlers on the main queue is generally a good thing. It lets developers use the library without getting encumbered by synchronization considerations (e.g., Alamofire). There are edge cases where you don’t want to use the main queue for completion handlers and where we are willing to add the overhead of our own synchronization code, but in simple cases, that just adds noise to our code unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but I don't think it makes much difference about the different queues,
you still have to "wait" until
the completions are done, for example:

```
var myItemsTotal: Int = 0

getMyFirstItem() { val1 in
    getMySecondtItem() { val2 in
        getMyThirdItem() { val3 in
            myItemsTotal = val1 + val2 + val3
            print(" myItemsTotal: \(myItemsTotal)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're making it serial while it doesn't have to be